# In a subclass of UIView, is there a method or delegate that will allow a caret to appear when the user is typing?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, caret

In my UIView, I have implemented  but that only allows the user to type text; it doesn't actually display the blinking line.

Is there a way I can get the caret to appear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

check link for reference
[Iphone textfield display cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358393/iphone-textfield-display-cursor)